# How do I debug a memory leak in a Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: memory-leaks, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox WebExtension with a memory leak. My current suspicion is it has to do with messages posted between components of the extension (i.e. with port.postMessage). How do I go about debugging this in Firefox?

I opened the Debug panel on my Temporary Extension, but it doesn't include the memory profiler tool. Does the memory profiler not work for extensions?

Answer (score -1):

You should try the Memory Tool in the Browser Toolbox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox